# How to make a div grow to contain its children elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have four responsive circles in one div. But the div has height and when you run code on a huge monitor, the circles are outside the div. I want to set the div's height to be the same as the circles' diameter. So after resize the div height will always be the same or bigger than circles.

```css
#circlediv {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="circlediv">
   <div class="kruh" id="circle1"></div>
   <div class="kruh" id="circle2"></div>
   <div class="kruh" id="circle3"></div>
   <div class="kruh" id="circle4"></div>
</div>
```

I tried `display: inline-block`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please add your remaining styling.

Comment: Can you create a complete snippet?

Comment: Your “example” doesn’t contain any circles. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This example uses `float` for the circles and `overflow: auto` for the container. From your comments to the other answers I am not sure if this is what you want, but it's one way to solve it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.kruh {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border: 1px solid #fa0;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circlediv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="circlediv">
  <div class="kruh" id="circle1"></div>
  <div class="kruh" id="circle2"></div>
  <div class="kruh" id="circle3"></div>
  <div class="kruh" id="circle4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using `display: inline-flex;`

```css
.kruh {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-flex;
    border-radius:100%;
}

#circlediv {
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="circlediv">
    <div class="kruh" id="circle1"></div>
    <div class="kruh" id="circle2"></div>
    <div class="kruh" id="circle3"></div>
    <div class="kruh" id="circle4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you mean?

```css
.kruh {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:100%;
}

#circlediv {
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="circlediv">
    <div class="kruh" id="circle1"></div>
    <div class="kruh" id="circle2"></div>
    <div class="kruh" id="circle3"></div>
    <div class="kruh" id="circle4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No because when you set circlediv to static height circles will be alway be biger then div on biger screen

Comment: he said " I want to set the div's height to be the same as the circles' diameter"